# How to join two interfaces declarations into one?

Tags: typescript

I have two properties of an interface:

```
export interface IInvoicesData {
    invoice: IInvoice;
    invoiceWithTotals: IInvoice & IInvoiceTotals;
}
```

This works fine and I make `invoiceWithTotals` property to contain properties from both `IInvoice` & `IInvoiceTotals` interfaces.

How can I move declaration `IInvoice & IInvoiceTotals` to its own interface so that replace `IInvoice & IInvoiceTotals` with something like `IInvoiceWithTotals` besides using `extends`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type IInvoiceWithTotals = IInvoice & IInvoiceTotals;
```

seems to work fine.