# typescript union of multiple types

Tags: typescript

All,
I have 4 typescript classes that are very similar and I can pass any of the 4 classes to the same function.  So my function signature looks like this.

```
foo(a:Plane |Rocket | Bird | Balloon) { dostuff;}
```

Is it possible to create a class or interface that is a union of all four

something like

```
class Flyer = Plane | Rocket | Bird | Balloon
```

Comment: If the classes are similar they should share an interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two interfaces declarations into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821192/how-to-join-two-interfaces-declarations-into-one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a type alias:

```
type Flyer = Plane | Rocket | Bird | Balloon;
```

This is only an alias; it will behave identically as if you had written it in its expanded form.